# Firebase and changes with React JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have an application in react js that runs on a firebase server. The problem I have is that every time I implement a change it is necessary to clear the navigation data. Is it possible not to have to clear the navigation data to visualize what has been modified in the application by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than deploy your ReactJS app every time you make a change, you should be using the [Firebase Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) while actively developing your code to test your code locally which will bypass the CDN that all static content served by Firebase Hosting passes through.

When testing deployed code, clearing your cache is the best approach. As any problems that come up will be problems of your users and you should handle them appropriately.

However, **during testing only**, you can also instruct Firebase Hosting to disable it's default 1-hour cache by manually configuring the [`Cache-Control` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) for all files as `no-store, max-age=0` (don't cache, always fetch from server). The documentation for this can be [found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache).

Make sure that when you are ready to release your project, **that you remove this**.

```json
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "headers": [ {
    // Disable Firebase CDN for all requests
    // TODO: Remove this before release
    "source": "**",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "Cache-Control",
      "value": "no-store, max-age=0"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```